# PHP variable-infused link not writing to a variable?

Tags: php, variables, file-get-contents

http://www.reecemcmillin.com/albums/

```
<?php
$uncut = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=active&source=hp&q=' . $_POST['band'] . '+' . $_POST['album'] . '+zip+inurl:mediafire');
$strip1 = strstr($uncut, 'www.mediafire.com/?');
$link = substr($strip1, 0, 30);
echo $link;
?>
```

It doesn't seem to be writing the website content to $uncut. Can somebody help me figure out what's wrong? Thanks.<3

Comment: Any errors occurring?  Use `error_reporting(1)` at the top to make sure error messages are displayed.

Comment: With other modifications of the code, when errors occur, they display. This just displays nothing at all.

Comment: Google will start responding to requests from your server's IP with a captcha if it gets any volume of requests.  Keep an eye on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clients are not supposed to send URI-fragments (the portion of the URI following `#`) to servers when they retrieve a document.  PHP is probably sending a request for the google homepage, effectively: `file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');`.  If you echo `$uncut`, that's probably what you'll see you're getting back.

Try a querystring-based URI instead.

```
<?php
$uncut = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=active&source=hp&q=' . urlencode($_POST['band']) . '+' . urlencode($_POST['album']) . '+zip+inurl:mediafire');
```

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=active&source=hp&q=bon iver+for emma forever ago+zip+inurl:mediafire) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /home/content/14/7415714/html/albums/results.php on line 2
----------
The "for emma forever ago bon iver" things are the terms I entered. I'm new to php, kind of stumbling along. I'm slowly but surely finding my way around things. :P

Comment: Try to `urlencode` the `$_POST` variables before adding them to the URL.